# disable tabular output for code block in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

When I execute a code block in org mode, the output will be tabularized. I want to use this functionality to build a set of commands which I can then execute in a new code block, so I have to remove all pipe characters first. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: May you please provide more detail and an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should set an output handling options in header arguments.

We need output *type*

> scalar, **verbatim** The results should be interpreted literally—they will not be converted into a table. The results will be inserted into the Org mode buffer as quoted text. E.g., :results value verbatim.

and output *format*

> **raw** The results are interpreted as raw Org mode code and are inserted directly into the buffer. If the results look like a table they will be aligned as such by Org mode. E.g., :results value raw.

Tabular interpretation is enabled by default (with implicit header args):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(number-sequence 1 5)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

To get raw output we need to change *:results* header argument to *verbatim raw*:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results verbatim raw
(number-sequence 1 5)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

or define that for whole header ([or any level](http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-header-arguments.html#Using-header-arguments)):

```
* Raw output
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:    :results  verbatim raw
:END:

#+begin_src sh
cat <<EOF
| 1 | 2
|--
| a | b
EOF
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| 1 | 2 |
|---+---|
| a | b |
```

[Org-babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/) provides more ouptut options. You can read about them at [Specific Header Arguments](http://orgmode.org/manual/results.html#results) and [Header arguments and result types in Org Babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/header-args.html).

Comment: Thanks. I meanwhile found another solution using `:results output`